# Copy data from a txt file into database

Tags: postgresql

I am using pgAdminIII and I want to copy data from a .txt file to my database.Let's say that we have a file called Address.txt and it has these values:

1,1970 Napa Ct.,Bothell,98011

2,9833 Mt. Dias Blv.,Bothell,98011

3,"7484, Roundtree Drive",Bothell,98011

4,9539 Glenside Dr,Bothell,98011

If I type

```
COPY myTable FROM 'C:\Address.txt' (DELIMITER(','));
```

I will get

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY address, line 3: "7484, Roundtree Drive",Bothell,98011
```

What do I need to add to the COPY command in order to ignore the `,` as a new column inside the `" "`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify quote character such that:

```
COPY mytable FROM 'C:\Address.txt' DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '"' csv;
```

Comment: Now I get `ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe9 0x70 0x61`
`CONTEXT:  COPY address, line 679`

Comment: It seems file isn't in `UTF-8. You can specify it via `ENCODING 'encoding_name'`.

Comment: Ok I changed it to UTF-8 and now I get `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1"`
`CONTEXT:  COPY address, line 1, column addressid: "1"` If I return to ANSI I will get the previous error.

Comment: Clearly, `"1"` is a correct syntax for an integer. I suspect conversion didn't work. Could you please ensure conversion or as I commented before you can give encoding to `copy` directly ?

Comment: Ok so I typed `COPY mytable FROM 'C:\Address.txt' DELIMITER ',' QUOTE '"' ENCODING 'UTF-8' csv;` and still getting the same error as before.

Comment: It's like `ENCOIDING 'UTF-8'` didn't change anything becouse if I convert my file to ANSI and type the same code I will get the error with the `...UTF8:...` and if I convert it to UTF-8 I will get the error with `...integer: "1"...`

Comment: Anyway I will try to solve it manualy becouse in other txt file the code works fine. Thank you anyway.